# How to delete an element from a collection association in Spring Data REST?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, http, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Suppose you have a One-To-Many or Many-To-Many relationship in Spring Data REST. Let's say you have groups that has a One-to-Many relationship with users. If you get the list of associations from a group you will get back links like this:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "users": [
      {
        "username": "test25",
        "enabled": false,
        "firstName": "strifng",
        "lastName": "sdfdffff",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "…/users/78"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "username": "test33",
        "enabled": true,
        "firstName": "sd",
        "lastName": "asdfsa",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "…/users/77"
          }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Which is useless if you are trying to remove a particular user from a group. You are either forced to use `PUT` with `/groups/{id}/users` but that is impossible if you have thousands of users. You **can** `POST` to `/groups/{id}/users` with a list of URI but you **can't** `DELETE` to `/groups/{id}/users`.

Why?

The only way `DELETE` works is by calling `/groups/{id}/users/{id}` but there's no way to construct this URI from the front end as it is not returned in the collection.

How do you get around this?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern that you'd need to use here is to access the association resource asking it for the `text/uri-list` media type, get the URIs of all linked resources, modify the list as you see need and `PUT` it back to the association resource. I.e.:

```
GET /groups/4711/users

200 OK
…/users/3149
…/users/41
…/users/4711
```

Followed by a:

```
PUT /groups/4711/users 

…/users/3149
…/users/4711
```

Basically removing the user with id 41 from the association.

### The problem

The problem with this suggestion is it that it currently doesn't work . It's broken in the sense that the lookup of the list of URIs currently fails due to some bug. Looks like that functionality went off the radar at some point (as it's not even advertised in the reference docs anymore). Good news is that I filed and fixed [a ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1458) for you. If you give the latest snapshots a try, the suggested protocol should be working.

### Some general considerations

In general it's hard to provide an API to generically remove individual items from a collection of associations. The HTTP `DELETE` method unfortunately operates on the target URI only and does not take any request body. I.e. you'd have to expose some kind of identification mechanism for the individual collection elements within the URI. There's no spec that I am aware of that defines how to do that and we don't want to get into the business of defining one.

One could investigate the ability to use JSON Patch requests to collection like association resources but that's not without problems either. I've filed a [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1459) to keep track of that idea.

Besides that a potentially ever-growing list of references to other resources is pretty hard to manage in the first place. It might be a better choice to augment the resources space with a custom resource that handles the unassignment of the user from the group and advertise that through a custom link.

Comment: Ok due to identification challenges, you are saying it's not easy to delete a resource via the DELETE method on the parent resource. So what is the best practise for the front end code to execute a removal? How does the front end construct the URI /groups/4711/users/41 for DELETE considering that ID is not commonly exchanged between frontend/backend?

Comment: @erotsppa The frontend/client should refrain from constructing URIs at all. In a REST environment a server should teach clients everything they need to know. If your collection-resource allows the removal of entries it should include links a client simply can use. Similar to the Web where a waste bin icon indicates a removal action the affordance in REST is communicated via link-relation names that should either be [standardized](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) or resolve around [Web linking extensions](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8288#section-2.1.2)

Comment: @erotsppa ... your frontend would then look for those link-relations and just invoke the accompanying URI. Also keep in mind that GET responses are cacheable by default and a cache will throw away a stored representation if it isn't considered fresh enough or a non-safe operation was performed on the [effective request URI](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234#section-4.4). The URI  therefore is more or less the key used by the cache for the respective response. As such custom URIs may prevent the correct invalidation of a response

Comment: @RomanVottner but that’s the problem. The front end should not construct the URI but the URI is *not* provided by the backend out of the box. SDR by default does not provide the means for the client to perform delete. I suppose what Oliver might say is that the server should create the links using linkbuilders but it’s extremely clumsy for such a common scenario. Again to illustrate the problem the server returns URI like this /users/41 but the client actually needs /groups/1/users/41 for DELETE

Comment: @erotsppa It is questionable whether each collection should automatically allow removal of elements by default, I'd say it is more of an edge-case than a normality. You can always add such links manually via something like `resource.add(linkTo(SomeController.class).slash(entity.getId()).withRel("remove"));` or the like in a `ResourceAssemblerSupport` class

Comment: @RomanVottner can you explain how this is an edge case? What am I missing? You would frequently add and remove items from collection.

Comment: I'd argue the best way is to make this state transition obvious and explicit in the API by providing a custom resource and pointing to that via a link. The generic way described above is of course getting out of hand easily as soon as you have to transfer a giant list of URIs back and forth just to remove one item.